# Auto update PowerShell script from Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: powershell, azure, md5, azure-blob-storage

I would like to automatically update a PowerShell script from Windows Azure Blob Storage if a newer version is available.

Pseudo code:

```
if <update available> {
  <download update>
  <restart Powershell script>
}
```

I did find the ContentMD5 property where the value is for example "r3zP0ehIwNxGVIMcB8AcCg==".

```
$StorageAccountName = "myAccount"
$StorageAccountKey = "myKey"

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$list = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container deployment -Blob myScript.ps1 -Context $context
$list.ICloudBlob.Properties.ContentMD5
```

Two questions.

1.
The ContentMD5 is calculated for a ZIP file but is empty for a PS1 file. Any idea why this is happening?

2.
How do I calculate the MD5 value myself?

I did find some code to calculate the MD5 from a local file. But the value is in a completely different format like for example "FA-0D-F6-22-7A-BF-AE-87-B9-F6-88-0C-AE-5B-75-E9".

```
$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($myScript)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making use of `ContentMD5` property, may I suggest you use [`ETag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.etag.aspx) property of the blob for checking if the blob has changed. `ContentMD5` property is a user-defined property and a user can update it anytime even if the blob was not updated. `ETag` property on the other hand is updated by the system every time a blob is updated.

**Update**

Regarding why the MD5 is not matching, basically you're converting the hash byte array to string. You would need to convert it into Base64 encoded string:

```
$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($myScript)))
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Good suggestion! But I guess I cannot calculate the ETag value myself so I have to store it locally somewhere for comparison? Preferable I would like to "extract" the value from the local version of the script.

Comment: Aah, I see. Yes, you're correct that you can't calculate ETag property. However the key thing is that you can't always rely on ContentMD5 property of the blob.

Comment: Please see my updated answer regarding MD5 hash mismatch. HTH.

Comment: Right! If I compare this output with the ContentMD5 on Azure it is the same. The only thing now remains is that the ContentMD5 is not always calculated. It is by default for ZIP files bot not for e.g. PS1 (PowerShell) files. Thanks a lot Gaurav Mantri!

Comment: How are you uploading the files? What's the size of files?

Comment: I was uploading the files using Azure Storage Explorer and noticed that it does not depend on extension but was indeed related to file size. At ~50MB the ContentMD was calculated. But when I use Set-AzureStorageBlobContent the ContentMD *is* calculated regardless the extension and size.